# Multitouch in Qt

Tags: application-development, qt, multi-touch, touchscreen

I've got a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 and Qt Creator/5.2.1, and I'm trying to get multi-touch working for the example applications like photosurface.

My input device is an Acer T272HL 10 point multi-touchscreen, xinput refers to it as "Advanced Silicon S.A CoolTouch(TM) System", and I've seen it tracking multiple touches using geisview, but nothing else in the system seems to recognize any multi-touch activity.

Any ideas how to get Qt to start listening to the same "channel" that geisview is using to get those multi-touches?

Thanks,

Update: Don't ask why, but I had 2 USB mice plugged in.  Removing the extra mouse enabled the pinch to zoom features in Chromium, but... even after a reboot, the Qt photosurface example is only responding to single touches from the touchscreen, no pinch to zoom or rotate.  Here's the current xinput feedback:

`$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Advanced Silicon S.A CoolTouch(TM) System id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

I'd really like to develop multi-touch enabled Qt apps for this system, but so far, they seem to be deaf to the multi-touch events.